# Is there an English equivalent of the Japanese proverb "Ron yori shōko"?

Tags: proverbs

There is a Japanese proverb that means "No matter what theories and assumptions you discuss, if they do not match the facts and examples, your argument is meaningless".

**Question:** Is there an English equivalent of this Japanese proverb?

**[Edit]** The Japanese proverb is not only used in the context of science. I am looking for an English proverb that is close in meaning to "Facts/real-life experiences/etc outweigh reasoning/common sense/what Wikipedia says/etc".

Comment: Anglophpones have the archetypal example with a *specific* scientific law that in and of itself constitutes "the final authority". [*The British astrophysicist Arthur Eddington gave a stern warning to would-be theoretical physicists in 1915. “**If your theory is found to be against the second law of thermodynamics I can give you no hope; there is nothing for it but to collapse in deepest humiliation**”.*](https://www.newscientist.com/definition/second-law-thermodynamics/)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - “Physics is to math what sex is to masturbation.” Dick Feynman (allegedly)

Comment: It doesn't matter how beautiful your theory is, it doesn't matter how smart you are. If it doesn't agree with experiment, it's wrong.” ― Richard P. Feynman

Comment: Perhaps my favourite: “Philosophy of science is about as useful to scientists as ornithology is to birds.” RPF.

Answer (score 1):

Its not really a canonical proverb but "Evidence trumps theory" has quite a lot of use:

> Empirical evidence trumps theory. In the hierarchy of evidence, EBM favours empirical evidence over theoretical knowledge ([source](https://philarchive.org/archive/ANJD))

> A fundamental value of science is that evidence “trumps” theory, in the sense
> that if evidence and theory clash then, generally, it is the theory that should be either
> discarded or modified ([source](https://e-space.mmu.ac.uk/628031/1/How%20Social%20Simulation%20Could%20Help%20Social%20Science%20Deal%20with%20Context%20-%2014th%20ESSA%20stockholm%20bok%20978-3-030-34127-5.pdf))

> Bottom line: theory is good, but experimental evidence trumps theory.([source](https://www.neuron.yale.edu/phpBB/viewtopic.php?t=1803))

Other examples can be freely found.

Answer (score -1):

There's a saying, "It's all fun and games until reality bites you in the ass".

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes - particularly given that ***Reality bites*** is [a known collocation with exactly this sense.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-meaning-of-the-phrase-reality-bites) Anyway - have a counterbalancing upvote on me! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  Thanks for the counterbalance.  :-)

Comment: Well, *There's always one,* as they say. So I don't usually think anything of it if there's just one inexplicable downvote. But it's very odd that you got TWO downvotes for such an "on point" answer. I find it hard to believe two silent downvoters both took issue with "ass" here. (For reasons that aren't exactly obvious, the BrE spelling "arse" always seems coarser to me, so yours is effectively the "sanitized" version! :)

Comment: "reality bites" is a known collocation, but I can find one single example of this as an expression (and that is in a tweet)

Comment: That was how the first fairy tale my mom ever read me ended. I can't remember the name, but I'll search for it.

Comment: Gosh!  it doesn't sound like any traditional fairy tale.  Do you really remember the first fairy tale? I'm sure I don't remember mine (but it probably ended "happily ever after")